# Dynamic Table replaces array elements with new data

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to build a dynamic table like below

[image]

Here I have added 1 row into the table.
 But when I add next row, the previous row in the table also get changed. Not just when clicking add. When ever I changed something on the header row, all the rows in the table get updated to the new value like this
[image]

Here is my code and template

```
<thead>
    <th style="width: 250px;">
        <label for="" class="control-label">Location</label>
        <select [(ngModel)]="selectedBudget.locationName" name="" class="form-control" id="">
            <option *ngFor="let location of locations" [value]="location.locationName">
                {{location.locationName}}
            </option>
        </select>
    </th>
    <th style="width: 100px;" class="text-center">
        <label for="" class="control-label">Days</label>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="selectedBudget.days" class="form-control" placeholder="Days">
    </th>
    <th style="width: 100px;">
        <label for="" class="control-label">Year</label>
        <select [(ngModel)]="selectedBudget.year" name="" class="form-control" id="">
            <option [ngValue]="2020">2020</option>
            <option [ngValue]="2021">2021</option>
        </select>
    </th>
    <th class="text-center">
        <label for="" class="control-label">Cost</label>
    </th>
    <th>
        <button type="button" (click)="addBudget()" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">ADD</button>
    </th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let budget of internalBudgets" [id]="budget.locId">
        <td>
            {{budget.locationName}}
        </td>
        <td>{{budget.days}}</td>
        <td>{{budget.year}}</td>
        <td>{{budget.internalCost}}</td>
        <td>
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Edit</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

My TS

```
public selectedBudget: InternalBudget;
public internalBudgets: InternalBudget[] = [];

addBudget(){

let rc:number = this.locations.find(x => x.locationName === this.selectedBudget.locationName && 
  x.year === this.selectedBudget.year).cost *  this.selectedBudget.days;
this.selectedBudget.internalCost=rc;

  this.internalBudgets.push(this.selectedBudget);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

It would be easy if you just pass parameters in your `addBudget()`
Example :

```
    addBudget(selectedLocation: Location, selectedDays: number, selectedYears: number) {
         let rc = location.cost *  days;
         this.selectedBudget.internalCost=rc;
         this.selectedBudget.days = days;
         this.selectedBudget.years = years;
         this.internalBudgets.push(this.selectedBudget);
    }
```

Comment: Why we need that since we have already those values in that object via two way binding

Comment: I don't see the double binding in your code! I answered the code bellow. Please add the full version

Comment: You are binding selectedBudget.* but the selectedBudget reference it is always the same. Even when you are pushing with `.push(selectedBudget)`. You are always pushing the very same reference, so when the biding is happening, it change all the elements of your array because all the elements are a replicated reference

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @shadowoviç for giving the hint where I did wrong. So I did that this way.

```
let ibCopy:InternalBudget= Object.assign({},this.selectedBudget);
this.internalBudgets.push(ibCopy);
```

Answer (score 0):

you actually need to create the object selectedBudget.
let newObject= {
  .... init your properties here
}
and then just push it tu your array

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question to specify those variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `.push({...selectedBudget});`